# How to mark a cmdlet parameter mandatory and if that parameter is not supplied, throw an exception

Tags: powershell

The default behaver for [Parameter(Mandatory)] on a parameter for a cmdlet, is to prompt the use to supply the parameter. I need it to throw an exception. As many of my parameters are objects and cannot be entered at this prompt, but also it blocks execution. When I run thing, I run lots of things, and just want to get a failure and move on to the next script.
But also, when run in a PS Job, the job just gets stuck, and you never see the prompt.

The cmdlet

function Write-Do {
param(
[Parameter(Mandatory)]
[string]$s
)
write-host $s
}

the output when running.

Write-Do
cmdlet Write-Do at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
s:

Comment: One option would be to not make the parameter mandatory and throw an 
 exception in the code if the parameter is null

Comment: The downside with that is I will lose the indication that the parameter is mandatory in the first place, when getting help with get-help. 

Is there no way to control the behavior of what is done when the parameter is not supplied?

Comment: @Daniel thats not one option, that is THE option. other than that what OP is asking is not possible.

Comment: You can use  a "default value" that uses a `throw` statement (enclosed in `$(...)`) to signal a missing mandatory argument by way of an _error_ instead of the default behavior of _prompting_. However, the unavoidable downside is that this requires you _not_ to use `[Parameter(Mandatory)]`, which means that the parameter's mandatory status won't be reflected in the command's syntax diagram.  See the linked duplicate for details.